# Can i copy the exact value instead of refencing another sheet inside a formula for multiple rows in EXCEL?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like the reference to another  sheet inside the formula to be replaced with the actual value instead of the reference. I cannot do it with special copy because it is inside a formula and i want to do it for several rows. Is its possible to be done? Thank you in advance.

```
    Year     Inflated Price             Price   Inflation
    1990    =(E9*70%)*Sheet2!C3         122     0.28888
    1991    =(E10*70%)*Sheet2!C4        125     0.36983
    1992    =(E11*70%)*Sheet2!C5        128     0.45078
    1993    =(E12*70%)*Sheet2!C6        131     0.53173
    1994    =(E13*70%)*Sheet2!C7        134     0.61268
    1995    =(E14*70%)*Sheet2!C8        137     0.69363
    1996     =(E15*70%)*Sheet2!C9       140     0.77458
    1997     =(E16*70%)*Sheet2!C10      143     0.85553
    1998    =(E17*70%)*Sheet2!C11       146     0.93648
    1999    =(E18*70%)*Sheet2!C12       149     1.01743
    2000    =(E19*70%)*Sheet2!C13       152     1.09838
```

Comment: Your request is not very clear : you MIGHT need a VLOOKUP : that unables you to fetch a result from a list. i.e : (A1 = 1 B1=90%, A2=2, B2=85%, ...) ; VLOOKUP(2;"A:B";2;false) will return 85% (content of B2 since 2 matched A2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that - though it's a bit tricky - see the instructions below.

However, quick word of warning beforehand - using values in any formula is usually not best practice. Already looking at `=(E9*70%)*Sheet2!C3`, the `70%` should not be in the formula, but in an external assumptions cell! Else it is a hidden assumption that is buried in the formula - and when you later look at your file - or somebody audits it - you'll have a hard time finding it - and knowing why you did it!

The same obviously applies to what you're intending, i.e. if you now also replace the linked inflation rates with hard coded inflation rates, this will be again some hidden assumption.

Anyway, enough 'lecturing' (sorry, couldn't help it!), if you still want to do it, here's the way to go:

1. In a new column, enter the part of the formula that you want to replace and let Excel calculate this part. I.e. if you want to replace, `Sheet2!C3` in your first column, place the formula `=Sheet2!C3` in this new column - and copy it down
2. Change your formulas from A1 style to R1C1 style. To do so go to File->Options->Formulas->Working with formulas and check R1C1 referencing style: [image]
3. Your formula `=(E9*70%)*Sheet2!C3` will now look something like `(RC[+2]*70%)*Sheet2!R[-6]C[1]`. The beauty of the R1C1 style is that relative references are now the same across the whole column, i.e. check the row below and you'll find the same formula!
   Now you can use Replace to remove the part from your formula that you want to replace with the value:

   1. Select the whole column
   2. In the Replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>), enter the part of the formula you want to replace, e.g. `~*Sheet2!R[-6]C[1]` - note that you must quote the `*` as `~*`!
   3. Press Replace All
4. Now select and copy the values from your support column from Step 2
5. Select the original column and use Paste Special->Values with the option "Multiply":[image]
6. Delete the support column and set the referencing style back to A1

Done!

Comment: I cannot thank you enough...this is by far the best answer i ever got than you so much...